# Selenium IDE 1.8.1 Alert box : cannot see the alert box while running the tests

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am writing the tests in selenium and Junit and importing the tests as Junit4 Remote control for web application , while I am running the tests it passes the steps but I am not able to see the alert opening but the test passes.

Why I am not able to see the alet box while running the tests??? I will be thankful to the answers.

assertEquals("Please enter valid city ", selenium.getAlert());

Answer (score 2):

Under Selenium, JavaScript alerts will NOT pop up a visible alert dialog. Selenium does NOT support JavaScript alerts that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until someone manually clicks OK.

1. to verify your alert use this: storeAlertPresent(variableName)
2. Retrieves the message of a JavaScript alert generated during the previous action, or fail if there were no alerts : storeAlert ( variableName )

So now you can assert this stored alert.

And There is one more command present, If you want to click on cancel button instead of OK button: chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation()